# Injecting @Singleton into @ApplicationScoped result in NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I'm running an ear in glassfish, using EJB and WAR module. The EJB module contains a singleton that manages connections to remote machines and, in case of particular events, send a message using JMS. The WAR module contains a websocket server that intercept the JMS messages and send them to connected browser. It works perfectly.
Now I'm introducing a "startup" method: when a new client connect I want to send it the list of the machines, so javascript can prepare the correct number of div. For doing it I have created a method in the singleton bean that return the list and I want to call it when the new session opens.

This is the singleton in the EJB module:

```
@Singleton
public class TServer implements ServerListener, TServerLocal {
  private HashMap<String, Servers> servers = new HashMap<>();

  @EJB
  private JMSQueueProducer jms;

  @Override
  public void connect(String hostname, String username, String password) {
    Server server = new Server(hostname, username, password);
    server.addListener(this);
  }

  private void onServerEvent(String host, String data) {
    this.jms.textMessage(host + " " + data);
  }

  [...]
}

@Local
public interface TServerLocal {

  public void connect(String hostname, String username, String password);
  public void disconnect(String hostname);
  public LinkedList<String> list();

}
```

JMSQueueProducer is a stateless EJB used only for sending message to the JMS queue:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class JMSAsteriskQueueProducer {

  @Inject
  private JMSContext jmsContext;
  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/serverQueue")
  private Queue sQueue;

  public void textMessage(String message) {
    jmsContext.createProducer().send(sQueue, message);
  }
}
```

This is the websocket server in the WAR module:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WebSocketServer {

  private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

  @EJB
  private TServerLocal tServer;

  @OnOpen
  public void open(Session session) {
    sessions.add(session);
    LinkedList<String> servers = tServer.list();
  }

  [...]
}
```

If I try to start a sessions I get a NullPointerException at tServer.list(), meaning that tServer is null.
I've tried changing @EJB for @Inject with the same result. I think it's perfecly legal to call an EJB inside a CDI, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to mention, in your `@EJB` annotation, the JNDI path of your  `TServerLocal` bean. Please refer to [Glassfish docs](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your @Singleton requires an [@LocalBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/LocalBean.html) annotation because it is exposing other interfaces besides the no-interface view:

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton
public class TServer implements ServerListener, TServerLocal {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using the TServerLocal interface, with Local annotation, I think it's should be sufficient. Anyway, tried putting LocalBean, nothing changes.

Comment: Read the javadoc for @LocalBean that I linked in the answer

Comment: I've read it, thank you for the pointer. Anyway, I've added the LocalBean annotation, but nothing changes.

Comment: Please show your Glassfish version and list the 3rd party jars in your deployment (because it looks like something else besides GF could be trying to manage the lifecycle of your WebSocketServer)